# Common fields on graphql interface type in react apollo with a graphene backend

Tags: interface, graphql, react-apollo, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a python graphene-django backend with an interface and two types, let's say

```
interface InterfaceType {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

 type Type1 implements InterfaceType {
    aField: String
}

 type Type2 implements InterfaceType {
    anotherField: String
}
```

I'm able to query this from my react-apollo frontend using inline fragments:

```
query {
  interfaceQuery {
    ...on Type1 {
      id
      name
    }
    ...on Type1 {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But [from what I understand](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) it should also be possible to query the common fields simply as

```
query {
  interfaceQuery 
    id
    name
  }
}
```

When I try this, however, I get the error `Cannot query field "id" on type "InterfaceType". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on "Type1" or "Type2"?`

I'm using an [`IntrospectionFragmentMatcher`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments/#fragment-matcher).

Am I misunderstanding and this kind of simple access of common fields is not possible, or is it just not implemented in either graphene or apollo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing that error, it's coming from the server, not Apollo. However, there's nothing specific to either Apollo or Graphene that should prevent you from querying the interface fields without a fragment.

The error is thrown because whatever schema you're using [literally doesn't have that field on the provided type](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/fa4eeda36029680205e20059379e89189b946032/graphql/validation/rules/fields_on_correct_type.py#L47). Maybe you updated your schema without restarting the service, or were mistaken about what fields were actually part of the interface -- it's hard to know with only pseudocode provided.

Comment: Yes there was a mistake in my backend code ‍♂️. Thanks!